Can we see real images with lens?
There was this question.

In an experiment to determine the focal length of a convex lens, a
student obtained a sharp inverted image of a distant tree on the
screen behind the lens. She then removed the screen and looked through
the lens in the direction of the object. She will see
(1) an inverted image of the tree at the focus of the lens.
(2) no image as the screen has been removed
(3) a blurred image on the wall of the laboratory
(4) an erect image of the tree on the lens

The answer given in my book is (2) but online and in other reference books the answer is (1). Can anyone give me the clarification on this?

Does this answer your question? Real images and their formation A real image is still there but it depends on the position of your eye as to whether you see a sharp image.  Also What is the apparent location of a real image formed by a lens?
